# VSFTPD Ubuntu won't start on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ftp

I have a server running Ubuntu 11.04 Server and I have installed vsftpd (FTP).
I am trying to get vsftpd to run on startup, but can't seem to configure it right.

There is already an upstart vsftpd file in /etc/init.d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is confgured to run under inetd? check vsftpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

The upstart config needs to be in /etc/init not /etc/init.d